# NetBeans: Php code is not displayed in the editor

Tags: php, netbeans

I have NB 7.3.1 version fresh instalation on fedora linux 19 KDE.
When i try to open php files code is not displayed in the nb editor from right side.
When i double click on helloworld.php he dont show me php code.

[image: PHP]

When i dbl click on index.html all works fine :

[image]

I dont know what is happening when i create new project i take PHP project. U see tab for hello world is empty in editior place on the top
Any solution for this?

**Update:** put ss for php 
[image]

Premissions:

```
[root@localhost html]# ls -l JoomlaResources
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 ikac ikac 4096 Aug 16 17:04 com_helloworld
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ikac ikac  232 Aug 16 16:58 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 3 ikac ikac 4096 Aug 16 16:58 nbproject
```

THanks!

Comment: That's the version history of the php file, not its contents. Apparently it has no history. Try opening the editor instead.

Comment: Are you sure you have the PHP plugin installed? Go to Tools->Plugins, then go to the Installed tab and make sure plugin name: PHP Category: PHP is installed and Active.

Comment: Man i say i make project like php application. @Mearlyn no bro again show me stupid history

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if it is some kind of permissioning problem since you are on Linux. Find the php file in your file browser and look to see who the owner and permissions are on it.

Comment: it happened to me !! just restart the netbeans. And there are two options on top left corner of source code window,'source', 'history'. make sure 'source' is selected

Comment: @Pitchinnate check my update for premissions

Comment: @ p.vansia nothing again show stupid history

Comment: I will now unistall and again try to install to see what is happening! Deam

Comment: After fresh installation again show history.. By By **NB** i will back eclipse